# Loading page gives an error in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

When I login, it gives me "error page not found". It's not loading the controller function.

This is my view file:

```
<form name="loginform" action="welcome/login" method="post">
Enter User Name:
<input type="text" name="uname">
Enter Password
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
```

This is my login controller file:

```
class Login extends Controller {
    function Login()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
    }
    function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

This is my welcome controller file:

```
class Welcome extends Controller {

    function Welcome()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Loginmodel');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->model('Loginmodel','login');
        $info = $this->logn->login();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$info);
    }
}
```

Can you give me any idea what is wrong?

Comment: `$this->logn->login();` seems to be a typo, double check your actual code if this was copy/pasted verbatim.

Comment: @Madmartigan: I agree with you. See my answer for a question by this guy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686964/show-records-ordered-with-maximum-price-first-in-php-mysql. Its answer with very fast and good trick by me but I got nothing from this guy no upvote no answer accepted. Why not they go through FAQ before start such activity.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems fine, so I would guess it has to do with this:

```
<form name="loginform" action="welcome/login" method="post">
```

The path is relative, which is only going to work if there are no url segments present. If the current URL is `/hello/world`, you will end up posting to `/hello/world/welcome/login`

Try a full URL or absolute path. Example:

```
<form name="loginform" action="/welcome/login" method="post">
                         <!-- ^^^ Note the leading forward slash -->
```

Or use `base_url()` for the full url:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/login">
```

You may also be interested in the [`form_open()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) function which will do this automatically.

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome/login'); ?>
```

The only other thing I can see would have to do with whatever `$this->login->login();` does. If you can confirm what your URL actually is when you see the "page not found" error, that would be a great help.

Comment: its still the same problem :(

Comment: @UmerSinghera: Can you please show us exactly what your URL looks like when you see the error?