# Show records ordered with maximum price first in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I store bike name and their prices.
Now I want show all my bikes ordered with maximum price (most expensive) first, as in:

```
bike 800 cc     1600$
bike 400 cc     800$
bike 200 cc     400$
bike 100 cc     200$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM bikes ORDER BY price DESC
```

check if datatype of price column is varchar then it will not work properly. So use below trick:

```
 SELECT * FROM bikes ORDER BY price+0 desc
```

This is a quick fix instead of sorting to CAST operator.

Comment: when 0000 is Added Result not Show Accurate .Can You Justify This ?

Comment: what is datatype of price column in table?

Comment: data type of price is varchar

Comment: Use numeric types to store numeric data; use date/time types to store date/time data.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  There's a white outline of a 'check mark' or 'tick' underneath each of the answers to a question you asked.  You can click on it to indicate that you've accepted this answer.

Comment: see it's just below vote count icon a tick mark icon,at left side of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM bikes
ORDER BY price DESC
```

Comment: Result Not Show Accurate Some Prices That Are Higly like adding 450000 they are not Working Perfect

Comment: The problem appears to be the wrong type for the price column; VARCHAR() is not an appropriate type for storing money values.

Comment: Could be even worse. I once was hired to fix an application. Order number was stored as VARCHAR(6). Eventually it had overflown and started erasing old orders. :-)